# How can I determine if an SSD drive is fixed drive or connected on USB?

Tags: c++, windows, usb, solid-state-drive

Is it possible to determine if an SSD drive is connected on USB or if is fixed disk (connected to motherboard)?

Comment: This is a platform specific issue and you forgot to mention the platform and OS.

Comment: I work in Windows

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, you can use [GetDriveType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea).

Sample usage:

```
UINT nType = GetDriveType(_T("C:\\"))
```

Return values for nType:

**DRIVE_FIXED**: 
The drive has fixed media; for example, a hard disk drive or flash drive.

**DRIVE_REMOVABLE**:
The drive has removable media; for example, a floppy drive, thumb drive, or flash card reader.

To check if it's USB drive, you must call for [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya).

You can find a sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947865/1410246) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3438366/1410246).